# Permission denied trying to start a new process from a Java application as root user (with non-installed JDK)

Tags: permissions, java, jdk

I try to start a new process using Java's `ProcessBuilder`, running as *root* user (during the prototyping phase). 
It works as expected when I run the application using a JDK installed with `apt`.

My requirement is to allow to use custom JDKs downloaded on-demand. I thought that unpacking the JDK tar.gz file and marking the commands in the `bin` folder as executable would be enough to make this "unpacked" JDK usable:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root 12328 Aug  3 22:33 java
```

But for some reason when I start the same application with this "unpacked" JDK's `java` command:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

export APP_HOME = "/opt/path/to/app"
export JAVA_HOME = "/opt/path/to/simply/unpacked/jdk"
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -jar $APP_HOME/app.jar
```

I get the following error when trying to start a new process using `ProcessBuilder`, no matter what I try to execute (even very simple commands fail, like `whoami`):

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/bin/whoami" (in directory "/opt/..."): error=13, Permission denied
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1140)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1074)
    at org.zeroturnaround.exec.ProcessExecutor.invokeStart(ProcessExecutor.java:997)
    ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:319)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:249)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1111)
    ... 13 common frames omitted
```

I have already tried two different JDKs (*corretto* and *oracle*) with the same result...

The Kotlin code is trivial, eg.:

```
    try {
        ProcessBuilder().command("/usr/bin/whoami").inheritIO().start().waitFor()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        println("whoami failed")
    }
```

I use Ubuntu Server 22.04.2 LTS.

The system is a simple default installation of Ubuntu Server, one partition, no network drives, etc. 
`/opt` is on the local disk as well:

```
$df -Th /opt/myapp/runtime

Filesystem                        Type  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ext4   98G   23G   71G  25% /
```

The output of `ls -l /usr/bin/whoami`:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/whoami
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 31232 Feb  7  2022 /usr/bin/whoami
```

Ps.: I'm a Kotlin/Java developer and a simple Linux user, Ubuntu is my preferred development OS - but I'm not a Linux power-user :)

Comment: Assuming you are calling a bash/sh script from the ProcessBuilder: how does the first line of your executable file look like? Can you execute it in terminal?

Comment: @kanehekili I edited the question to reflect that the execution of very simple commands (like `whoami`) fails, too. So I guess that executing more complex command would work as well when the cause of the problem is solved...

Comment: Are you using `sudo` to run the command as root? Is "/opt" mounted? Mount option of "/opt" ?

Comment: "Is "/opt" mounted?" - I guess so because starting of the new process works if I run the same Java application using a `java` command installed by apt.
"Mount option of "/opt" " - how can I check this?

Comment: "Are you using sudo to run the command as root?" - no, I run it directly as root.

Comment: How is "$JAVA_HOME" mounted? Mount options of "$JAVA_HOME" ?

Comment: @marco, sorry, I don't know what you mean... JAVA_HOME is simply set to an absolute path (`/opt/myapp/runtime/jdk-oracle-linux-x64-20.0.2`), like in my extracted example above.

Comment: is "/opt" on the local disk ? is it an own partition? add output of `df -Th "/opt/myapp/runtime"` to the question.

Comment: @Marco, `/opt` is on local disk, there is only one partition as I know :). I added the output of `df`.

Comment: I am not a kotlin developer :-) I just tried with corretto-17 the same way as you described (besides the errors in the script). It worked.

Comment: can you add the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/whoami` to the question.

Comment: I’m running into the same issue. Did you figure out what was casing this?

Comment: @Edi sorry, no...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem and the solution was to `chmod +x lib/jspawnhelper` in the JRE folder.

Comment: Thanks for posting this Edi. After upgrading from Java 11 to Java 17, we started getting these sorts of `Permission denied` exceptions on basic Linux commands called from our Java based installer.  Your suggestion of `chmod +x $JRE_HOME/lib/jspawnhelper` fixed the issue for us.